# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio is broken

Tags: sql-server, ssms

It has multiple copies of each button:

[image: It has multiple copies of each button]

[Link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiHvG.png)

How do I get rid of this problem. Restart won't work.

Also I'm getting warning when I launch SSMS

[Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FU2zB.png)

Comment: What is your SSMS version?

Comment: @miriamka 15.0.18390.0 latest

Comment: The latest version of SQL Server **Management Studio** (the GUI / Query tool) is **v18.10** which you can [download from here](https://aka.ms/ssmsfullsetup)

Comment: @marc_s whoops I wrote build instead of version but I have the same version as you sent me

Comment: Did you have multiple versions of SSMS installed in parallel ? Have you tried completely removing SSMS (just SSMS - not SQL Server itself) and re-installing the latest version?

Comment: This is something wrong with your SSMS installation.  You should definitely re-install it.

Comment: @marc_s i've never had previous versions of ssms. I tried everything, reinstalling both sql server and ssms - everything is useless. Also im getting error message at the start, ill attach it to the question

Comment: You may need to take this question to the MSDN forums.  It's definitely something wrong with the installation/configuration that is supposed to be handled by the installation procedure.  There may be a corruption in your binaries, or something else.